# Max number of columns in column-direction flex

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it possible to set a maximum number of columns for a column-direction flexbox? I'd like these columns to not create a third column when the second column fills. Instead, I'd prefer if it could overflow such that both the first columns were extended, keeping the order of elements.

[image]

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kzsLucpd/), my code is also below:

```css
div.columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div.columns>div {
  width: 60px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
   <div>foo 1</div>
   <div>foo 2</div>
   <div>foo 3</div>
   <div>foo 4</div>
   <div>foo 5</div>
   <div>foo 6</div>
   <div>foo 7</div>
   <div>foo 8</div>
   <div>foo 9</div>
   <div>foo 10</div>
   <div>foo 11</div>
   <div>foo 12</div>
   <div>foo 13</div>
   <div>foo 14</div>
   <div>foo 15</div>
   <div>foo 16</div>
   <div>foo 17</div>
   <div>foo 18</div>
   <div>foo 19</div>
   <div>foo 20</div>
   <div>foo 21</div>
   <div>foo 22</div>
   <div>foo 23</div>
   <div>foo 24</div>
</div>
```

If flexbox is the wrong tool for this, what would be a better fit? I don't have to support any old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Flex columns usually require the container to have a fixed height, you might want to try using [css columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) instead

```css
div.columns {
  columns: 2;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div.columns>div {
  width: 60px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div>foo 1</div>
  <div>foo 2</div>
  <div>foo 3</div>
  <div>foo 4</div>
  <div>foo 5</div>
  <div>foo 6</div>
  <div>foo 7</div>
  <div>foo 8</div>
  <div>foo 9</div>
  <div>foo 10</div>
  <div>foo 11</div>
  <div>foo 12</div>
  <div>foo 13</div>
  <div>foo 14</div>
  <div>foo 15</div>
  <div>foo 16</div>
  <div>foo 17</div>
  <div>foo 18</div>
  <div>foo 19</div>
  <div>foo 20</div>
  <div>foo 21</div>
  <div>foo 22</div>
  <div>foo 23</div>
  <div>foo 24</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know of css columns! One thing that's missing from this solution is that the first column doesn't fill before the second column does. Flexbox columns would only introduce the second column if the first one filled up. Do you think that's possible to solve with CSS?

Comment: I think the only way to do that would be to use `column-fill: auto` but that would mean you would need to set a height on your container again: https://jsfiddle.net/p5oerucj/.  However this means that if you have too many items for the container, they won't show: https://jsfiddle.net/8hvw3uLy/2/.  Perhaps you could get around this by setting the max height to cover the maximum number of children, but if it's going to be dynamic, I would just go with the above and just spread it evenly over the 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative option, if the number of elements (for example from the backend) and the desired number of columns are known, you can be applied `display: grid` and `grid-auto-flow: column`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.columns {
  --col-width: 60px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), var(--col-width));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(calc(var(--items) / var(--columns)), auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.columns > div {
  width: var(--col-width);
  padding: 0 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!-- Suppose you know that there are 24 elements, and you need to create 3 columns   -->
<div class="columns" style="--items: 24;--columns: 3;">
  <div>foo 1</div>
  <div>foo 2</div>
  <div>foo 3</div>
  <div>foo 4</div>
  <div>foo 5</div>
  <div>foo 6</div>
  <div>foo 7</div>
  <div>foo 8</div>
  <div>foo 9</div>
  <div>foo 10</div>
  <div>foo 11</div>
  <div>foo 12</div>
  <div>foo 13</div>
  <div>foo 14</div>
  <div>foo 15</div>
  <div>foo 16</div>
  <div>foo 17</div>
  <div>foo 18</div>
  <div>foo 19</div>
  <div>foo 20</div>
  <div>foo 21</div>
  <div>foo 22</div>
  <div>foo 23</div>
  <div>foo 24</div>
</div>
```